# Confirmation mail with activation link is not apearing in console

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-email

I have writen the code for signup in which after entering the name and password it will redirect us to email sent page as well as it suppose to send mail in console but it is not appearing.

### views.py

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('user/account_activation_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        user.email_user(subject, message)
        return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'user/register.html', {'form': form})
```

### settings.py

Email configuration in settings.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

---

### urls.py

This is the url mapping used below.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', signup,name='sinup_user'),
    path('password_reset/',auth_view.PasswordResetView.as_view(), name='password_reset'),
path('password_reset/done/',auth_view.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/done',auth_view.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
    path('account_activation_sent/', account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', activate, name='activate'),
```

]

path('reset///',auth_view.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),

### account_activation_email.html

This is the console template have beed used.

```
{% autoescape off %}
Hi {{ user.username }},

Please click on the link below to confirm your registration:

http://{{ domain }}{% url 'activate' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

### Console

The below wordings are apearing in console but mail is not showing up here.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 12, 2019 - 12:50:55
Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'music.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[12/Oct/2019 12:51:41] "GET /user/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4282
[12/Oct/2019 12:52:03] "POST /user/register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Oct/2019 12:52:03] "GET /user/account_activation_sent/ HTTP/1.1" 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the email backend is set correctly in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

Also, the code that sends the email should be indented under the 'if form.is_valid():' otherwise you will get redirected to 'account_activation_sent' even if the form is invalid.

The 'else:' clause also needs indenting correctly.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            subject = 'Activate Your MySite Account'
            message = render_to_string('account_activation_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            user.email_user(subject, message)
            return redirect('account_activation_sent')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Also see https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html

Or you could use django-allauth that does all this for you and just modify the default templates.

Comment: Indentations are corrected actuly it posted like that by mistakely in the question. I refered the same link as you mentioned above and just done the same thing as they told in that site and EMAIL_BACKEND also I have setted exactly as they told but still it is not solved

Comment: What about 'from mysite.core.forms import SignUpForm' and replace SinupForm with SignUpForm

Comment: Please could you post the templates and urls.py

Comment: Corrected SignUpForm it is not throwing any error as it before but still it is not sending any mail at console

Comment: are user.email_user(subject, message) & return redirect('account_activation_sent') indented 12 spaces now?

Comment: Chris I have done copy and paste the code you given above but the it has not solved. I tried to put url mapping here but stack is not allowing to do that

Comment: System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 12, 2019 - 12:50:55
Django version 2.2.6, using settings 'music.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[12/Oct/2019 12:51:41] "GET /user/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4282
[12/Oct/2019 12:52:03] "POST /user/register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[12/Oct/2019 12:52:03] "GET /user/account_activation_sent/ HTTP/1.1" 200 67

Comment: Actuly it is not throwing any error. I just added url mapping can please look at it mean while I will upload template also

Comment: you're getting a redirect code (302), try pointing to the correct view in urls.py: path('register/', views.signup, name='sinup_user')

the 'account_activation_sent' in urls.py will also need attention

Comment: all the urls pointing to the correct url only. i realy fed up of this don't no where it went wrong.

Comment: in urls.py:

from django.conf.urls import path
from mysite.core import views as core_views

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('signup/', core_views.signup, name='signup'),
]

If you're getting a 302 response code in your console then the urls aren't right.

Answer (score 0):

I have made mistake in url pattern.

### urls.py

url with wrong pattern

```
path('signup/', user_views.signup,name='sinup'),
path('account_activation_sent/', user_views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', user_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

url pattern after correction

```
path('account/signup/', user_views.signup,name='sinup'),
path('account/account_activation_sent/', user_views.account_activation_sent, name='account_activation_sent'),
path('account/activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', user_views.activate, name='activate'),
```

I had to add account/ befor the url starts that I was missed now it is working fine.